# Getting error: type object 'x' has no attribute 'objects', while defining custom queryset and model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am facing difficulty in integration of custom manager and queryset for django models with django-rest. I have defined a custom manager named 'manager'. But rest_framework requires that manager must be available as 'objects' in the model.

Following is my django code :-

> custom queryset and manager

```
class ActivableQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def all(self, return_all=False):
        if return_all:
            return super(ActivableQuerySet, self).all()
        else:
            return self.get_active()

    def get_active(self):
        return super(ActivableQuerySet, self).filter(is_active=True)

    @transaction.atomic
    def delete(self):
        for obj in list(self):
            obj.delete()

    class ActivableModelManager(Manager):
        _queryset_class = ActivableQuerySet

        def all(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self._queryset_class(self.model, using=self._db, hints=self._hints).all(*args, **kwargs)
```

> models.py

```
class DictStrModelMixin(Model):

    class Meta:
        app_label   = 'generic_models'
        abstract    = True

    def __str__(self):
        return str(model_to_dict(self))

class ActivableModel(DictStrModelMixin):
    is_active       = BooleanField(editable=False, null=False, default=True)
    manager         = ActivableModelManager()
    class Meta:
        abstract    = True
        _default_manager = "manager"

    def delete(self, *tupargs, **kwargs):

        pre_delete.send(sender=self.__class__, instance=self)

        self.is_active = False
        self.save(force_update=True)

        post_delete.send(sender=self.__class__, instance=self)
```

class ActiveSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ActivableModel
        fields = '**all**'

Now, invoking ActiveSerializer.save() gives me the following error :-
type object 'ActivableModel' has no attribute 'objects'
Following is the line of code in rest_framework, which gives me this error

[image]

Why is it so ? Doesn't django provides default manager 'objects' for all the models ? I have also tried setting _default_manager option in Meta class, but it doesn't work. What's the correct way to define custom manager and queryset in django ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assigned your manager to `manager` in ActivableModel, rather than `objects`.

Comment: I don't want to have objects as manager in my model. But django rest framework code requires it. Is there any way out ?

Comment: Why don't you want it?

Comment: I have defined custom manager and queryset. I want to set the instance of custom manager to objects. But since objects is not so meaningful, I want to use other term like 'manager'. But it doesn't work with django-rest, as it expects 'objects' in model class. Is there any way to mitigate it ? Also let me know, If I am doing anything wrong or there's a better way of doing it. Moreover, please specify it in your answer, so that It can be upvoted.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good reason. `objects` is the standard and expected way to name your default manager;  far from being "not so meaningful", it's understood by all Django programmers. The only thing you'll accomplish by calling your manager something else is confusing anyone who looks at your code.

Answer (score 1):

> Doesn't django provides default manager 'objects' for all the models ?

No. It does so only if you don't explicitely provide a manager yourself.

Also filtering the results of the default's manager `all queryset is usually a rather bad idea, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#default-managers

wrt/ your problem with `BaseSerializer` (wherever it comes from), you can submit a patch to the author with a proper implementation looking for `_default_manager` instead of `objects` (cf the above link), *but* as Daniel Roseman mentions, naming your default manager anything else than `objects` will mostly annoy (to say the least) anyone working on your code.